# Can you explain the grammar of В чем проблема? to me?

Tags: падежи, phrase

In a Memrise course В чем проблема? is translated as "what's the problem?"

Could you explain which case `В чем` in in? Проблема looks like Genetive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to look at this pattern is literally (albeit not too idiomatic) "Wherein lies the problem?"

> **in what** (is) (the) **problem**?

Other examples:

**В чём ра́зница?** - what's the difference? Lit: In what does the difference lie?

**В чём де́ло?** - What's the matter?

**В чём беда́?** - What's the harm?

**В чём я был непра́в?** - What was I wrong about?

Answer (score 4):

В чём проблема? -> В чём есть проблема? -> In what the problem is? That is Nominative case.

"В чём" marks the Prepositional case yet the object is missing here because it's a question. Consider "В чём проблема?" (What's the problem?) - "Проблема в тебе" (You're the problem).